# how to add "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD" format on add-log-time-format

Tags: format-time-string

- i am trying to create change log for all files edited on emacs using `add-log-time-format`
- however, as of now, `add-log-time-format` provides only 2 formats: 1. ISO8601 date `YYMMDD_ 2023-12-12` and 2. current time string `Wed Dec 13 00:07:35 2023`
- i would like to add time format of `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD` as per [w3c Date and Time Formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

There are *three* choices when you customize `add-log-time-format` (at least since 2015): the two you listed *OR* you can write your own function and customize `add-log-time-format` to specify `Other` with your own function as the value.

The function can be as simple as this:

```el
(defun my/add-log-iso8601-time-string-with-extras (&optional time zone)
  (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%:z" time zone))
```

which can be added to your init file. Then `C-h v add-log-time-format` will bring up the doc string of the indicated variable. Click the `customize` link, select the `Other` radio button, type (or better yet, cut-and-paste) the name of the function in the text box (where, by default, it says `ignore`), then `Apply and save`. Then try to add a log entry. You should probably restart Emacs and try it again to make sure everything is set up correctly.

Comment: @jindam: did this work for you?